# How can runtime systems support "GC" on compiled binaries?

Tags: c++, c, haskell, memory-management, garbage-collection

So basically I only know some basic concept of GC:(

I am new in functional programming language, and when I am studying the Haskell's runtime system, [RTS](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html), I found that RTS support GC for the compiled binary from Haskell.

So I am confused with this part, is there a separate process created by RTS that can do GC stuff towards Haskell binaries?

What's more, if so, is there any GC implementation for C/C++ ? (Suppose programmers only use kinda of "smart pointer" to use memory, and they don't need to care about memory management, GC process will take care of it)...? As far as I know, it seems that .net can work in this way... am I right?

Comment: Have you searched the internet for "garbag collector for C"?

Comment: You say "I am relatively familiar with ... concrete GC techniques used in Sun's JVM". Is this actually true? Do you understand card marking, tenuring, scavenging, etc.? Or are you saying you're familiar with how GC works from the perspective of someone writing Java code? Also, are you familiar with how the C runtime works on your platform of choice? Do you know how `malloc` and `free` actually work? It's hard to tell from your question exactly what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you will be less surprised that this is possible once you realize that the GC isn't free -- it requires cooperation from the binary that's using it, e.g., to allocate memory through the runtime system rather than in an arbitrary way. Of course, since the binary is built by GHC anyway, this is an easy thing for GHC to guarantee; it simply inserts the appropriate cooperation at each allocation point.

Comment: C++ programmers use RAII for automatic memory management, not garbage collection.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, you are right and I feel shamed that I claimed myself "I am relatively familiarXXX"... thank you!

Comment: @DanielPryden Sorry I should not shameless claim myself "I am familiar with XXX" I changed the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a separate process created by RTS that can do GC stuff towards Haskell binaries?

Garbage collection does not, in general, *require* a separate process (e.g., a "background" process), although some virtual-machine garbage collectors might do that (I don't know).

Think of the garbage collector as being merged with the heap allocator. Whenever you ask for some memory to be allocated, you invoke the heap to do so (which may hang for some time before finding a chunk to allocate). With a garbage collector, there is simply an additional step where the garbage collector first checks if it should do some collecting before allocating some memory.

What is central to garbage collection is the instrumentation (or annotation) of the memory to be able to infer which chunks of memory are still referred to / reachable. This kind of instrumentation simply implies additional operations during certain key points, like allocation, deallocation (if there is an explicit mechanism for it), and setting / getting pointer values (which are usually "hidden" under-the-hood in a garbage collected language, as opposed to languages like C/C++ that have "raw" pointers).

> What's more, if so, is there any GC implementation for C/C++ ?

Yes, there are all sorts of GC implementations for C/C++. They are not very popular (AFAIK), probably because C is low-level enough that things are usually manageable, and C++ has RAII (and smart pointers) which almost-completely eliminates the need for GC.

But if you really want GC for C/C++, you can certainly get it. There are both non-deterministic GC libraries (similar to JVM or .NET) and deterministic GC libraries (similar to PHP or Python).

> As far as I know, it seems that .net can work in this way... am I right?

Yeah, .NET like Java, is garbage collected. From a GC user's perspective, .NET is about the same as the JVM, as far as I know.

Comment: Minor nitpick: I don't believe that RAII or reference counting is the same thing as GC. Pretty much by definition there is no such thing as "deterministic GC" on general-purpose hardware. The reason true GCs are non-deterministic is because they're exploiting the time-space tradeoff of batching the work of deallocation -- allocation can be fast (most modern GC allocators effectively just do stack allocation), but it's deallocation that's expensive. So you batch up that work to prevent heap fragmentation and improve throughput.

Comment: @DanielPryden I actually agree completely with you (and I was just debating that point a few days ago). I said "deterministic GC" just because it's a common term for a global entity (or instrumentation) that ensures that no leaks are allowed (usually with reference-counting and a cycle detector). I also tend to prefer the term "GC" for only the JVM-style collectors, because it actually tracks garbage and collect it in batch, as opposed to deterministic schemes that simply prevents (eagerly, maybe too much so) garbage from even being created. And great points about the GC trade-offs!

Comment: Smart pointers do not eliminate the need for GC, since they can't handle cyclic references. Yes, yes, there are weak pointers, but they leave to programmer the decision if reference should be weak. So the memory will leak even with so called 'smart' pointers. They also add overhead and don't improve allocation speed.

Answer (score 3):

> So I am confused with this part, is there a separate process created by RTS that can do GC stuff towards Haskell binaries?

No. Why would there be? You don't need a separate process to do GC. The Java JVM doesn't need a separate process. You seem to have some confusion somewhere. All you need is some code in the runtime library.

> What's more, if so, is there any GC implementation for C/C++ ?

Yes.

> As far as I know, it seems that .net can work in this way... am I right?

If you mean that .NET has GC you're correct. If you mean that it's done via smart pointers or a separate process you're wrong.